# Google page speed says "Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data"

Tags: images, photo

I keep getting this error message from Google page speed and now have spent 48 hours trying everything. I am starting to look like a panda with black eye sockets from late nights.

I have tried EWWW optimizer and have optimized the pictures. I have smushit installed when the site started and thought that would take care of it but a year down the track I find that I am in the mess i thought I wouldn't be.

I have tried, hammy but it wasn't compatible lazyload just to get the load better that is also not compatible and send me a white page.

I have tried imsanity. but every time I go to page speed loads I am only getting the title response properly format images to save data. I have been on this site now for about an hour trying to find an answer.

Does anyone know what I can do that doesn't involve taking every picture down of the 500 or so pictures that I have would take an age.

Answer (score 1):

You can batch process images with an image optimizer. So if you keep the same images names and overwrite the old version of your images, then you wouldn't have to change anything in your code.

For example you can use tools like  **jpegoptim** to optimize **jpeg** or **[optipng](https://superuser.com/q/604487/158197)** for **png** images. They can be executed in batch mode decreasing each image file size accordingly.